# Calling function from the MainActivity scope

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app, I defined a function within the `MainActivity` scope, as:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     fun connectWebSocket() { }
}
```

This is because I want to use the `runOnUiThread` in my `connectWebSocket()` function.

In another `BroadcastReceiver()` I'm trying to call this `connectWebSocket()` as:

```
class MyLocationService : BroadcastReceiver() {
    connectWebSocket()
}
```

But I failed and got this error:

> Unresolved Reference: connectWebSocket

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where and how are you using `MyLocationService`? It does not seem to be related to your `MainActivity`.

Comment: It's impossible to see `connectWebSocket` method from `MyLocationService` class if it is not an inner class of `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In broadcast receiver you have onReceive method with context argument, you can cast it to your activity and call connectWebSocket()

```
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if(context instance MainActivity){
        ((MainActivity)context).connectWebSocket()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use activity scoped method in another component, we can use static reference of it like below:

```
class MyLocationService : BroadcastReceiver() {
    companion object {
       var mainActivity: MainActivity? = null
    }
    fun do () {
       mainActivity?.connectWebSocket()
    }
    fun clean() {
        MyLocationService.mainActivity = null
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     init() {
        MyLocationService.mainActivity = this
     }
}
```